# Insert Mysql with PHP - problem with foreign key insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
[project_select]
UserID (fk) | project_id (fk) | project_category_id (fk)

[project_category]
project_category_id | category

[projects]
project_id | projectname

[project_user]
UserID | Name
```

How can I insert Data with php in the tables **project_category**, **projects** and **project_user**, to get automatically the values in the project_select table with the FK's?

**Update:**
How can I merge this 3 queries into one line?

```
INSERT INTO project_category
VALUES (1,'Fruits')

INSERT INTO projects
VALUES (4,'Apple')

INSERT INTO project_user
VALUES (2,'Adam')
```

**and** get this values with this one query in the project_select table:

```
[project_select]
UserID (fk) | project_id (fk) | project_category_id (fk)
    2              4                  1
```

Comment: @elmanio what exactly do you mean by "How can I insert Data with php in the tables project_category, projects and project_user, to get automatically the values in the project_select table with the FK's?". I guess many others did not understand completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function to retrieve the id you just inserted.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (4,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2', 'Stavanger')");
$person_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

So, do inserts on your tables, call mysql_insert_id() after each insert, store inserted IDs and finally use the IDs in the mysql command to create the join table.

Comment: no, I want the same with the [project_select] table, how can I insert value in the tables, to get the value automatically in the FK field?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Using mysql_insert_id to retrieve the newly created primary keys on your three tables will give you the keys to insert into project_select.

Comment: It should work for what you want but there's no way to insert into three table, store the PKs and then insert them into another table all in one query.

Comment: thank you, what's the best method to insert my Data in all 4 tables? with mysql_insert_id? can you show me an example pleas?

Comment: I found a very good example on this page http://www.desilva.biz/mysql/insertid.html thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that I understood your problem correctly. But if you want to have the values entered automatically in `project_select` table? Then how about using MySql triggers? But be sure you are well aware of the database internals before using it.

[What are triggers?, Setting up triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387/setting-up-mysql-triggers)

But, please describe this -

> problem with foreign
>   key insert?